# Is there a way to pass through select numbers when parsing a string column that contains a name and number in python?

Tags: python, string, dataframe, parsing, split

I have a column in python `Name` that reads in football team names and a number such as `New Orleans Saints +2`

I parse the data into 2 separate & additional columns as `Name2`: `New Orleans Saints` & `Name3`: `+2`

I do this by using this line of code: `NameSeparate=dt['Name'].str.split(r'\s(?:([+-]?\d{,100}\.?\d{1,100}?))', expand=True)`

Then `dt[Name2]` = `NameSeparate[0]` & `dt[Name3]` = `NameSeparate[1]` separates and creates the 2 new columns

I have an issue when the code pulls in `San Francisco 49ers +5` as the code parses the `49` instead of the `+5`

I've tried writing a check loop in but can't get the script to pass through the `49` and just pull the `+5`

The name will always come in as `San Francisco 49ers` however the 2nd piece can have either a `+` or `-` sign in addition to any number following, for example it may come in as: `San Francisco 49ers +5`, `San Francisco 49ers -5`, `San Francisco 49ers +8.5`, `San Francisco 49ers -8.5`, etc.

Can someone please help me write a check for this issue? Thank you!

Comment: Are the team names in a pandas dataframe in a column named `Name`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case there is always a `+` or a `-` in front of the number which should be in the second column, you should remove the `?` after `[+-]` in your regex for splitting the original column:

```
NameSeparate=dt['Name'].str.split(r'\s(?:([+-]\d{,100}\.?\d{1,100}?))', expand=True)
```

Otherwise, you also select numbers where no such sign is placed before, as you already noticed.

If there are also entries where the number has no `+` or `-` before it, you can add an `$` to the very end of your regex string, which denotes the end of the string. Since the number seems to always come last, this also should work:

```
NameSeparate=dt['Name'].str.split(r'\s(?:([+-]?\d{,100}\.?\d{1,100}?))$', expand=True)
```